# Change url of WordPress site.

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, drupal

I am changing my site from Drupal to WordPress. There are many articles written.
Every article has url like given below.

```
http://example.com/blog/simple-post
```

How can I achieve this in WordPress. 
For now I am using.

```
http://example.com/simple-post/
```

Comment: remove blog from your articles link

Comment: @DeebanBabu i want 2,3 types of url. like /portfolio/simple-post,,,,/team/team-member,,,,

Comment: you can use seperate post types(custom post type) for team, and portfolio otherwise use categories for posts and add category in url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set it up in **settings->permalink** and set the option to custom type, then you add this type of permalink : **/%category%/%postname%/** instead of just **/%postname%/**

Then you **just assign any category to your posts, like blog, shop, portfolio, team etc** whatever you want without having to worry how to set that permalink for lets say two, three types of urls

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the exact same URL structure, look at "Permalinks" under the "Settings" option in the admin section.

You can set a custom permalink structure like:

```
/blog/%postname%/
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit permalinks in wordpress settings page

Custom Structure    http://example.com **/blog/%postname%/**

If you need category in url

Custom Structure    http://example.com **/blog/%category%/%postname%/**